How can I hide clear, next month, previous buttons in HTML date input?
I want to remove these clear button, next month arrow button, previous month arrow button (that has red color border)  from HTML date picker.

Below I have added my RangePicker component and css file.
import React, {FC} from 'react';
import './../../assets/styles/range-picker.scss';

type RangePickerProps = {
    dates: {start: string, end: string};
    handleChange: (dates: {start: string, end: string}) => void;
};

const RangePicker:FC<RangePickerProps> = (props) => {
    const onStartChange = (event) => {
        props.handleChange(
            {...props.dates,
                start: event.target.value,
                end: addDaysToDate(event.target.value, 30)
            }
        );
    };
    console.log(props.dates);
    const onEndChange = (event) => {
        props.handleChange({...props.dates, end: event.target.value});
    };

    function addDaysToDate(startDateStr, daysToAdd) {
        const startDate = new Date(startDateStr);
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + daysToAdd);
        return startDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];
    }

    return (
        <div className='d-flex range-picker'>
            <input type='date' id='start-date' className='px-2 py-3 date-picker'
                   value={props.dates.start}
                   onChange={onStartChange}
                   // onChange={(event) =>
                //    props.handleChange({...props.dates, start: event.target.value})}
            />
            <input type='date' id='end-date' className='px-2 py-3 date-picker'
                   value={props.dates.end}
                   min={props.dates.start}
                   max={addDaysToDate(props.dates.start, 30)}
                   onChange={onEndChange}
                   // onChange={(event) =>
                //    props.handleChange({...props.dates, end: event.target.value})}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default RangePicker;

@import "variables";

.range-picker {
    gap: 5px;

    .date-picker {
        border-radius: $radius-sm;
        border: 1px solid $border-color-primary;
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
}

I tried to do it by using css. But didint work.

I guess there’s no straightforward way to do it, so you can get the class names when it’s open and use display: none.
